# Using PullToRefresh in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

In official examples of [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) one can not scroll the list while loading more data in expandableListView. But it works normally in the custom list where the item has no child. I have searched the internet but failed to dig out something useful, it seems that no one has ever come across such an issue.

Comment: Ok. Where is problem?

Comment: @PankajKumar When I pull and release, it would work normally like fetching data and updating the list, the problem is that I can do nothing with the UI when it is loading data, I can not scroll nor touch, and it would come to life after loading...

Comment: Hey @withparadox2   Were you able to figure it out. I am also facing the same issue with ExpandableListView.

Comment: @user1288005 You can change `private boolean mScrollEmptyView` to `private boolean mScrollEmptyView = true;` in `PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase.java` under the package `com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library`

Comment: Its already the same code in PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase.java